# How can I display a sticky on the side of a webpage when the user scrolls past a specific height/component of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to be able to add a sticky on the right side of my webpage which only displays when the user scrolls past a specific height/particular component in the web page. How can I achieve this?

Attaching the screenshot for your reference.

**This is how the page looks like before the person scrolls, so there is no sticky on the side**

[image]

**This is how the sticky should pop up on the side of the page once the person scrolls below the Popular links on top**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself, and explain what is not working with your current attempt. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Looking into intersectionObserver might help.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score -1):

Initially you can set **display property** of Popular links to **none**.

then you can use **scroll** event for this like

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
console.log(e);
var popularLinks = document.getElementById("pop-links")
popularLinks.style.display = "block";
})
```